# Scala: List.iterator produces empty iterator

Tags: scala

There are problems when converting a list to an iterator using built-in methods.

1. Calling `iterator.hasNext` changes the value of `iterator.size`.
2. `iterator.hasNext == false` even on a non-empty iterator *before* any iteration has occurred.

Any ideas on what may cause these problems?

```scala
val list = scala.collection.immutable.List(1, 2, 3)
val iterator = list.iterator
println(iterator.size) // 3
println(iterator.hasNext) // false
println(iterator.size) // 0
```

Confirmed locally on Scala version 2.11.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_72).

Confirmed on IdeOne [here](http://ideone.com/D3jB6m).

Comment: From the Iterator docs API: "It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise, one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it. ". This includes the `size` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Computing the size of an iterator consumes it as the size is not stored. I think that it is working like intended, even though the API (i.e. offering size for an iterator) is misleading.

Comment: What do you mean by "devouring?"

Comment: Good catch, wanted to express an "evil" version of misleading. Thought that terms expresses what I meant, but it does not.

Comment: I approve of the "devouring" word choice, I was a little peaved when I discovered this quirk myself (just today actually).